# In a Web Client - RESTapi - RDB system, what should be responsible for user authentication?

Tags: postgresql, authentication

I'm starting a new project that will consist of 3 components:

- Single Page Web Application
- REST api, written in node.js using the express framework
- Relational Database, Postgres

Users will be authenticated with some sort of token (jwt or the like)

Now, I'm a bit spoilt. I've only ever made a complete application with CouchDB, where it's possible for all user-authentication to be handled by the database. Everything else I've done, someone else handled the authentication stuff.

Looking at other projects, it seems like the REST api is responsible for a lot of security concerns. This strikes me as just plain wrong. I'm not used to the database trusting the api. I'm wondering if this is considered best practice.

For example. Say I have a blog with comments. The comments live in a table with the following columns:

- commentId
- blogPostId
- userId
- commentText

I want the commentText to be editable, but only by the user who owns the comment.

I would have a function in postgres like this (psuedo-code):

```
// userStruct has 'id' and 'token' properties
function updateComment(userStruct, commentId, newCommentText) 
{
    oldComment = getOldComment(commentId)
    if(oldComment.userID != userStruct.id) throw "unauthorized user"
    return performCommentUpdate(commentId, newCommentText)
}
```

But, how do I know that the userStruct's token matches it's id?

What's the best practice?

- Does every Postgres function that gets called by the api first call Authenticate(user) to check if it has the right token?
- Or, is this all done in the REST api? (i.e: the database trusts the api)
- Or, should I be using some sort of middle-ware?
- Or, is this one of those everyone has their own opinion sort of situations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, it looks like the answer is to use middleware, and yes the database trusts what it's given.

I've decided on [passport.js](http://passportjs.org/)

It authenticates the user's request before the request gets to your api code, and responds with 401 if they're not authorised.